Given a vector field find $V$ on a manifold $M$ s.t. $V_p \neq 0$, find a chart $(U,\phi)$ containing $p$ where $\partial_{x_1} = V$
Given a vector field find $V$ on a manifold $M$ s.t. $V_p \neq 0$, find a chart $(U,\phi)$ containing $p$ where $\partial_{x_1} = V$.
I have tried to approach this problem in two ways. The first one is completing $V_p$ to a basis of the tangent space and considering the integral curves, but I do not have the techincal tool to prove that I can do this in a smooth way and that the integral curves give actually a set of coordinates. I do not want to overkill the problem using frames or more advanced notions
The second one is to use in inverse function theorem, and in particular parametrize the curve using one o the coordinates and then replace the chosen coordinates with the point of the curve and rearrange the coordinates to have the new curve-coordinate as the first component.
Is this idea correct?
Thank you in advance for any answer!
